How to review questions with votes to close?
Is there a way to see all questions that currently have votes to close by someone? Seems like it would be useful to have community members be able to look through any questions with close votes all at once to weed out bad questions/spam/dupes quicker.

If you have access to moderator tools, there is a button in the upper bar named "tools" that shows you which questions have close votes.
If you don't have enough reputation, that button is named "review" and it doesn't show that information as far as I know. You can, however, see a list of low quality posts, which might help.

thanks. good to know. another couple weeks and i'll be there I think ;)
